# Azure: Switching app to another App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have a lot of web apps, each has their own app service plan. I'm looking to consolidate them into a few plans to better managing the resources that they need.
Will switching to a new app service plan cause any down times on the apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there will be a small moment of downtime. Your app is migrated to another set of servers after all.